# SharePoint Document library - vertical view

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, list-view

Does anyone know of a way to change the orientation of the table view so rows are vertical as opposed to horizontal?

The document library contains around 87 columns & using SharePoint '13 online.

Any help / advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The only OOB solution that I am aware of is to use the `Style` feature in the list view settings.  The `Preview Pane` and `Boxed` types both are vertically orientated, but it's not a full transposed list view that you're looking for.

[image: list view settings - style]

**Preview Pane:**

[image: preview pane example]

**Boxed:**

[image: boxed example]

Answer (score 0):

Views from top to bottom are a way to save a preset to help organize the columns you see along with Sorting, Filtering, Grouping etc. 87 columns is a lot so only you will know the best way to organize them. With that said your goal should be to make standard SharePoint views that roll things up to the key columns that define the content your organizing such as Category, Status, and other uniquely defined business data.

If you were to start over or simplify the amount of columns you have to better help you organize your content how would you do that? Sometimes there is a point of having to many columns or folders to organize your files so it becomes difficult to know where to go. Think about the high level purpose of the files in your library and how can you divide up the "pie" so you can find it in useful ways. You can always make a couple of libraries so the columns that organize them can be different. Site Columns and Content types are another way of dividing up different types of content to make things re-usable on your sites.